# Facebook Share Button breaks my SSL/HTTPS

Tags: facebook, ssl, https

Facebook Share Button breaks my SSL/HTTPS connection in Chrome. Chrome is displaying a red HTTPS with a (/) slash displaying acroess the https.

Its states:

> Your connection to XXXXXXXXXX.com is encrypted with 256-bit encryption. However, this page includes other resources which are not secure. These resources can be viewed by others while in transit, and can be modified by an attacker to change the behavior of the page.
>
> The connection uses TLS 1.0
>
> The connection is encrypted using AES_256_CBC, with SHA1 for message authentication and DHE_RSA as the key exchange mechanism
>
> The connection is not compressed.

**How can I fix this issue? My code for Facebook is listed below:**

```
name="fb_share" 
share_url="https://mysexywear.com/product_details.php?prodId=<?php echo $prodId;?>&catId=<?php echo $catId;?>" 
href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php">Share

src="http://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"
```

Comment: Beware that [Share button](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/share/) is deprecated. You may want to use [Feed Dialog](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/) instead

Comment: that file doesnt load with https

Answer (score 4):

Try using a relative protocol, like so:

```
name="fb_share" share_url="//mysexywear.com/product_details.php?prodId=&catId=" href="//www.facebook.com/sharer.php">
```

Answer (score 3):

try this url ;)

```
https://facebook.com/connect.php/js/FB.Share
```

Comment: @newtostackoverflow, this URL is perfectly working! What you saying is wrong, that would mean that the whole `facebook.com` have invalid certificate which is not the case!

Comment: Because not working with Chrome and IE, certificate issue come up, be careful.

Comment: i have tried it my self in a production web site "https://www.sajilni.com/" with no problems in all platforms, please check it first.

Answer (score 2):

`src="https://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share" type="text/javascript"`

Surely that would work?

Comment: Even better is to omit scheme name at all to allow browser to use current scheme, like this: `//static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share`

Comment: chrome and firefox do not load this. Because the SSL certificate for this is invalid. Any alternative..??  @JuicyScripter

Comment: @newtostackoverflow, Facebook Sharer is deprecated, stop using it! If you really need use old, deprecated (and in some cases broken) functionality it's still located on  `//facebook.com/connect.php/js/FB.Share`

Answer (score 0):

use this codes:

```
<script>
   function fbs_click() 
       {
           u=location.href;
           t=document.title;window.open('http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u='+encodeURIComponent(u)+'&t='+encodeURIComponent(t),'sharer','toolbar=0,status=0,width=626,height=436');
             return false;
       }
</script>
<style> 
    html .fb_share_link {  
       height:18px; 
       display:block; 
       float:right; 
       margin-top:1px; 
       width:57px; 
       background:url(https://www.kiraguru.com/images/fbshare.png) no-repeat top left;   
      }
</style>

<a rel="nofollow" href="http://www.facebook.com/share.php?u=<;url>" onclick="return fbs_click()" target="_blank" class="fb_share_link"></a>
```

Change the " https://www.kiraguru.com/images/fbshare.png " field and change style code for your custom design.

!!! Important ->  You have to use https:// for share button image.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Referencing this link to the Share Button JavaScript code will return a Security Certificate error warning in each of the major web browsers:
https://static.ak.fbcdn.net/connect.php/js/FB.Share

Until Facebook resolves the issue it is not possible to acheive a satisfactory user experience that uses the JavaScript-implemented Share button within a website served over https.

I'd suggest one of two workarounds:

1)  Implement a "fake" Share button by creating a Share URL and applying it to an image:

```
<a href="https://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.your_url_encoded_webaddress.com" target="_blank">
  <img src="../images/Share_Button.png" border="0" />
</a>
```

2)  Use one of Facebook's non-deprecated Social Plugins ("Like" or "Send") to achieve similar functionality.  Both of these are still fully supported and work over https:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/